# Variable storage issue

Tags: python, variables

So I wrote a Python script on my phone to control Roku TVs and it works great, but...
When I use the standard method to find a Roku device on the Network it returns the First Device to respond, so...
I added Store and Recall buttons to Make it easier to cycle through devices on the Network... (Some logic was used to make it so the Store button only shows if the Device it finds isn't already stored, etc... And Recall is set to cycle to the Next Device Stored in the list after the one it's on...)
This works so far, however...
I'm storing/reading variables in a file because the Tkinter Background Canvas and Buttons are in a loop so Global variables are continually reset.
Normally, I would just pass variables to a second (memory) script and read them back on each event.  But the phone only runs one script at a time.
Is there a better way to keep the variables in memory (namely the current device)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Imports come first then
#defs read the file to a variable
#After defs I find the first Roku device to respond
#I'm writing that as a variable to a file

Store_Location = open('/storage/emulated/0/Movies/Roku/MMemory.ini', 'w')
Store_Location.write(location)
Store_Location.close()

#It works
#Then Tkinter and buttons are standard and work then after buttons I

root.mainloop()
```